# FeedBack For the Community (That is WE)

Tags: discussion, feedback

I am beginning to form an opinion that most of the users in meta are hardly bothered in reading the question completely. All they want to do is downvote. It's like a mad race. In many of my previous questions, I had to explicitly write something like this.

> I am not requesting for a feature. It's some help that I need from the community.

Even asking for help is apparently wrong in Meta. I understand if there is no research efforts or is a poorly written question then the question deserves a downvote.

Today's two classic examples [How to answer a question in a declined flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219595/how-to-answer-a-question-in-a-declined-flag) and [Random Downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219582/random-downvoting). I can give more if required.

In the first example, I somehow was not surprised by Tim's comment. Trust me this is what we have become. **A Downvoting machine**. I asked two SO members yesterday if I should post a question on meta. You know what was their reply... "**Best Of Luck!!!**"

Honestly? Situations have become that bad in Meta?

In the Second example, the question was closed as duplicate without even reading what my actual question was in-spite of me highlighting the exact question. That duplicate question was no where even close to the question that I asked besides being a duplicate of some other question. This clearly shows how attentive we are to questions :( **If you go through the edit history and the comments under the question, you will see how frustrated I was with the responses I was getting.**

Just wanted to share what I felt and I am sure there are many who share the same feeling...

Please note that I am not aiming specifically at these two examples. The above are just examples. So let's keep these out of the discussion and talk more in general about various posts.

If I am wrong then there is nothing to worry about. But what if I am right? What do you think should be done to make our users comfortable? I would definitely love to hear your opinion.

Comment: LOL Downvote in less than a minute? Just ascertains my point. Thank you

Comment: I've seen and removed some of your requests for downvote explanations. Especially on the "random downvoting" one, given all the comments that were necessary for clarification or indicate confusion, I would not be surprised that the regular "unclear what you're asking" was the reason. Which is a fair enough vote. But that's of course a guess by me, and I can't speak for the voters.

Comment: The first question was heavily upvoted, im somewhat confused by it as an example

Comment: @Richard I would hazard a guess that those were sympathy upvotes in response to Tim Post's comment.

Comment: Although I very rarely downvote (and didn't in this case) 'Random downvoting' came very close for me. I still don't fully understand what you were exactly asking. In part because there was acomment discussion in response to requests for clarifications rather than an edit to the question

Comment: I don't really need to read the full question to downvote this, reading the first paragraph is enough.

Comment: @SiddharthRout the biggest issue with your question is you took too long to get to the point.  99% of the time, when someone is complaining about downvotes, even when they say "it's not about the rep", it is about the rep.  You could have structured your question a lot better to make your actual question much more clear from the beginning.  As it was written when I saw it, the point was lost in a lot of words and background.  I didn't even see your point until I read the comments.

Comment: @RichardTingle it was a -3 or -4 when I first saw it before Tim's comment had an impact

Comment: Right, people downvote on Meta. So? Why is this so bad? Would you prefer the other way around, people upvote everything and thus no way to know what is a welcome feature and what isn't? That's how we express opinions, and -1 here because I think it's a pointless rant that doesn't lead to any constructive direction.

Comment: Here's another classic example: [Should we allow Questions/Answers about password cracking](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137086/should-we-allow-questions-answers-about-password-cracking) - Oh, wait!

Comment: @psubsee2003: See this is my problem. People either read part of the question and decide not to read further like Yannis did or you who thought that I took so long to explain things. If you see the original question before the edit, you would have seen that I had structured my question very neatly so there was no reason for any confusion. Did you see the comments below the question... Having said that this question is not about "My Question" Please... Please... spend some time reading the above rant and try to understand what I am trying to share here. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Another assumption from you I guess? Where did I say that? I am saying about people who downvote recklessly without even reading the question properly...

Comment: @SiddharthRout I read the question, I understand your point, and you provided only 2 specific examples.  I was trying to explain that there may have other factors in 1 of the examples.

Comment: Anyways... I won't be commenting any more. I just shared what I felt like... If one seriously has the time and patience then please try to understand what am I trying to share here. Else feel free to downvote...

Comment: @SiddharthRout Please stop saying that, it creates a self-fulfilling prophesy

Comment: @SiddharthRout what assumption? Where did you say what? You said people downvote recklessly and I explain why it's not reckless but rather got a reason behind it. It's not an assumption, it's coming from years of experience in Meta including many downvotes on my own posts.

Comment: @SiddharthRout So you are not interested in discussing anything here? This is going to be a one-sided statement with no further comments? Fair enough, then we might just as well close this.

Comment: **ack**, 5 seconds away from posting a response. Regardless, my conclusion was: Downvotes (which aren't on feature requests) are an indication that a question is unclear, this should lead to editing the question itself to clarify it. Adding “Edited:” sections only confused the matter further as the edited section will be in opposition to the main question

Comment: Sorry about that @RichardTingle. But yeah, I couldn't agree more with that statement.

Comment: @RichardTingle you can still post answer even after question is closed, just re-enable the button. If you want I can post a CW answer using your comment as contents then you can edit it as you like.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Really, thats quite a trick. I would have no objection to that. Thanks

Comment: @RichardTingle done.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks

Comment: One more day, and the old song goes. "Down vote indicates bad content, but be aware and do not ask what is wrong in your answer because users must be free to downvote you because they dislike your avatar". (gradually disappear, until only the smile remains in the air)

Comment: related: **[Is it possible on MSO to question something that people hold dear without getting “disagreement downvoted”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208876/165773)**

Comment: @Bart: yes, I have thought about it for quite few days with a more cool mind. I guess you are right. This should be discussed rather than swept below the carpet!

Comment: Reopened, as it's been edited to something that no longer fits the close reason.

Answer (score 5):

> I am beginning to form an opinion that most of the users in meta are
>   hardly bothered in reading the question completely. All they want to
>   do is downvote, downvote, downvote, downvote

This is not my experience, my experience is that people on meta vote! and they vote hard! If its up its really high up, if its down its really far down. Very few things are left to die at 0.

> Today's two classic examples
>   [How to answer a question in a declined flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219595/how-to-answer-a-question-in-a-declined-flag)
>   and [Random Downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219582/random-downvoting).
>   I can give more if required.

Both these questions feel unclear (and were more so when first posted). Random-downvoting in particular had examples that were unrelated to the question which were never removed. So people never removed their downvotes.

Downvotes (which aren't on feature requests) are an indication that a question is unclear, this should lead to editing the question itself to clarify it. Adding “Edited:” sections only confused the matter further as the edited section will be in opposition to the main question

Comment: `Adding “Edited:” sections only confused the matter further as the edited section will be in opposition to the main question`... oh my yes.  The only people that this helps is the people reading at that exact moment in time, and those people usually know what;s going on enough not to require it.  Any other time, all it does it makes me start looking for context.

Comment: @Richard see above comment. Downside of our little trick is that you won't get auto notified of comments, but I'll forward them to you like I did now.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks, although anyone reading these comments will hopefully now realise that

Comment: @RichardTingle well, with lower than -8 this doesn't appear in the front page anymore (not even when bumped by edit) so I don't expect much traffic. But it was important to make such point so thanks! :)

Comment: Well some _can_ be left at 0 score, but they usually have multiple (i.e. 15+) votes each way.